# Is there anyway to use proxy only while loading script files and rest are loaded normally?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, proxy

There is a proxy for which I only want to load script files while loading and using a website but not the others. I have tried some thing but it is not working.

I am using chrome extension for this. Here is the background.js code for that

```
const proxyConfig = {
   scheme: "http",
   host: "abc.com",
   port: 31112,
   username: "username",
   password: "password",
};

function encodeProxyAuthHeader(username, password) {
   const credentials = `${username}:${password}`;
   return `Basic ${btoa(credentials)}`;
}

chrome.proxy.onProxyError.addListener((err) => {
   console.log(err);
});
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
   function (details, callbackFn) {
      console.log("on auth required called");
      console.log(details);
      callbackFn({
         username: proxyConfig.username,
         password: proxyConfig.password,
      });
   },
   {
      urls: ["<all_urls>"],
   },
   ["asyncBlocking"]
);
// Set up the proxy configuration
chrome.proxy.settings.set({
   value: {
      mode: "fixed_servers",
      rules: {
         singleProxy: {
            scheme: proxyConfig.scheme,
            host: proxyConfig.host,
            port: proxyConfig.port,
         },
         bypassList: [""],
      },
   },
   scope: "regular",
});

// Intercept and modify HTTP requests
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
   function (details) {
      const proxyAuthHeader = encodeProxyAuthHeader(
         proxyConfig.username + "a",
         proxyConfig.password
      );

      details.requestHeaders.push({
         name: "User-Agent",
         value: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36",
      });
      details.requestHeaders.push({ name: "DNT", value: "1" });
      details.requestHeaders.push({
         name: "Proxy-Authorization",
         value: proxyAuthHeader,
      });
      return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
   },
   { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
   ["blocking", "requestHeaders", "extraHeaders"]
);
```

The issue in this approach is all the requests are handled by proxy. Because once `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired` is called it doesn't look for `Proxy-Authorization`. And if I remove the `onAuthRequired` listener it shows authentication dialog when I visit website. Is there any way I could decide for individual requests that whether it should use proxy or not.

If it is not possible in any way please give a solid reason why it is not possible.